# C code using pThreads compiles fine but gives a seg fault, used gdb to no avail

Tags: c, pthreads, segmentation-fault

Hi I am trying to run this code in terminal on a mac and it compiles just fine but when I try to execute it seg faults.. when I run gdb is states invalid memory address 000000 or something to that effect.. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define MAX_THREADS 512

void *compute_pi( void * );


int sample_points;
int total_hits;
int total_misses;
int hits[ MAX_THREADS ];
int sample_points;
int sample_points_per_thread;
int num_threads;



int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  /* local variables */
  int ii;
  int retval;
  pthread_t p_threads[MAX_THREADS];
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  double computed_pi;

  /* initialize local variables */
  retval = 0;


  pthread_attr_init( &attr );
  pthread_attr_setscope( &attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM );

  /* parse command line arguments into sample points and number of threads */
  /* there is no error checking here!!!!! */
  sample_points = atoi(argv[1]);
  num_threads = atoi(argv[2]);

  /* uncomment this block if you want interactive input!!!! */
  /* if so...comment out the two statements above */
  /*  
  printf( "Enter number of sample points: " );
  scanf( "%d", &sample_points );
  printf( "Enter number of threads: " );
  scanf( "%d%", &num_threads );
  */

  total_hits = 0;
   sample_points_per_thread = sample_points / num_threads;

  for( ii=0; ii<num_threads; ii++ )
    {
      hits[ii] = ii;
      pthread_create( &p_threads[ ii ], &attr, compute_pi, (void *) &hits[ii] );
    }

  for( ii=0; ii<num_threads; ii++ )
    {
       pthread_join( p_threads[ ii ], NULL );
       total_hits += hits[ ii ];
    }

   computed_pi = 4.0 * (double) total_hits / ((double) (sample_points));


   printf( "Computed PI = %lf\n", computed_pi );


  /* return to calling environment */
  return( retval );
}


void *compute_pi( void *s )
{
  int seed;
  int ii;
  int *hit_pointer;
  int local_hits;
  double rand_no_x;
  double rand_no_y;

  hit_pointer = (int *) s;
  seed = *hit_pointer;
  local_hits = 0;

  for( ii=0; ii < sample_points_per_thread; ii++ )
    {
      rand_no_x = (double) (rand_r( &seed ))/(double)RAND_MAX;
      rand_no_y = (double) (rand_r( &seed ))/(double)RAND_MAX;
      if(((rand_no_x - 0.5) * (rand_no_x - 0.5) +
      (rand_no_y - 0.5) * (rand_no_y - 0.5)) < 0.25)
    local_hits++;
      seed *= ii;
    }

  *hit_pointer = local_hits;
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Did you learn how to use `gdb` on a multi-threaded program? Did you compile all your program with `-g -Wall` ? And I would suggest having dozens, not hundreds, of (often running) threads...

Comment: No I dont know how to do that..  My professor provided this code and stated it should work with gcc and it compiles fine but seg faults when I try and run it. However when I turn to him and provides no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I compile with -ggdb, run the program in GDB with no cli args, I find that the segfault is in atoi.  Looking at the code, I see:

```
sample_points = atoi(argv[1]);
num_threads = atoi(argv[2]);
```

which are not proceeded by a check of `argc` to verify that `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` will be there.

If I run with this command line:

```
 ./a.out 500 8
```

I get this result:

```
  Computed PI = 2.616000
```

In short, I suspect you are running the program incorrectly, and as supplied it isn't very good.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass two parameters to the program. It is bad that this program does not check whether there is missing parameter. I will insert

```
if(argc<3){
    printf("Usage: %s [samples] [threads]\n",argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

before

```
sample_points = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to issue with not checking argc which has already been answered, atoi() has been deprecated, and you should consider using strtol() instead.

It is likely that the man page for atoi() on your system mentions this as well.